# RefObject in useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to use a RefObject as a dependency of a useEffect, but I know this is not good practice. It seems that a useCallback should be used, but I don't know how to integrate it into my code.

I know the following code isn't right, but here's what I'd like to do:

```
  const checkboxRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkboxRef.current?.checked) {
      console.log('Menu is open');
    } else {
      console.log('Menu is closed');
    }
  }, [checkboxRef.current.checked]);
```

Comment: You can't use ref, because changing the ref, doesn't cause a re-render. You should use a state, with an `onChange` handler.

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks, I forgot about onChange. It doesn't work properly, but at least I know which direction to look.

Comment: You can use ref, but you have to change another state so the component rerenders

Comment: @Konrad Yes, I've tried that before, but I didn't really like it. I've used another solution that I don't like either, but at least it works.